# Trying to unset an element from a JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm having some issues trying to unset a specific element from a JSON, what I have is something like that:

```
<?php
$json = '[{"contract":"0xb999803ee7087559eb601a4939c2d5da7668385a"},{"contract":"0x8880093d0759e485239d3010a47b80wesh5b6507daae"},{"contract":"0x77100c19ec711f0c4d6a4b38dad0b16f07aa74fe"}]';
$json_decode = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($json_decode as $item => $value){
    if ($value=='0x8880093d0759e485239d3010a47b80wesh5b6507daae') 
    {
        unset($json_decode[$item]);
    }
}

$json_decode = array_values($json_decode);
echo json_encode($json_decode);

?>
```

What I'd like to have afterwards is a JSON like this:

```
[{"contract":"0xb999803ee7087559eb601a4939c2d5da7668385a"},{"contract":"0x77100c19ec711f0c4d6a4b38dad0b16f07aa74fe"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, my if statement was wrong, I had to do it like this:

```
    if ($value['contract']=='0x8880093d0759e485239d3010a47b80wesh5b6507daae') 
    {
        unset($json_decode[$item]);
    }
```